# QGIS processing scripts - restrict vector input to geometry type

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, user-interface

In QGIS processing scripts we define input vector layers by

```
##inputlayer=vector
```

wich in the gui generates a drop down list from what the user can select one of all available layers.

Normaly, processing is defined for only one distinct geometry type, let's say `Point`. If the project contains of a great bunch of, let's say `Line` Layers, we have all these `Line` layers in a dropdown, where only the `Point` layer should be selectable.

So the question is:

In QGIS processing scripts, is there a way to restrict vector input to certain geometry type (sth. like `##input=vector point`)?

Comment: Did you try `##input=vector point`? ;)

Comment: No, just guessed, but: funny, it works! This is not in the doku (at least the german ver.), but, yes, that's the answer :-)

Comment: Nah, I don't think it's mentioned in the English docs either (or atleast I couldn't find it). But a very nice guess! Post it as an answer as atleast then it will be documented on the internet =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guess in my question really works. So as I have tried so far the declarations

```
##input_points=vector point
##input_lines=vector line
##input_polygons=vector polygon
```

are valid and restrict the combo box to the declared geometry type.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 3.x, suppose you have an input file using the template file; the following code is used:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    """
    Here, we define the inputs and output of the algorithm along
    with some other properties.
"""

# We add the input vector features source. It can have any kind of
# geometry.
self.addParameter(
    QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
        self.INPUT,
        self.tr('Input Layer'),
        [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry] # accepts any geometry
    )
)
```

The default input will look like this in the tool:

[image]

You can change the default line `[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]` that accepts any geometry to use only specific geometry as follows:

```
[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint] # accepts only point geometry.
[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine] # accepts only Line geometry.
[QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon] # accepts only polygon geometry.
```

In the case of *point* geometry, the tool will look like this after customizing the above line for *point* geometry:

[image]

In the case of *polygon* geometry, the tool will look like this after customizing the above line for *polygon* geometry:

[image]